# using image in if statement

Tags: c#, image, if-statement

how can i use image in if statement?

for example i want to check in click event of a picturebox that if a specific image(for example image1) is in it,then do some work.thanks in advance

update:

like this
the picturebox can be null or have an image in it,i want to check image1 is in it or not

```
    private void pictureBox34_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (///picturebox34=image1)
        {
            f();
        }
    }
```

now when i compile this code i took error:cannot convert system.drawing.image to bool

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying you want to know if the Image object is equal to a different Image object? Or are you wanting to compare the individual bytes of an image to see if they match? Some kind of image detection algorithm?

Comment: Show sample code for initializing or adding item to your control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have all the images loaded into memory then you could simply perform a reference comparison between the Image object assigned to the PictureBox and the other Image objects to determine which one is in the PictureBox.

Alternatively when you assign the `Image` to the `PictureBox` you can set the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property of the `PictureBox` to identify the Image and use the value of the `Tag` property for the test in your event handler. Of course in this case you only need the one Image in memory, but you will have to have some kind of identifying information, like the name of the image to assign to the Tag property.

**Update**: Based on your updated question, it seems you are happy to perform a refernce comparison. Which you can do as follows

```
private void pictureBox34_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (picturebox34.Image == image1) 
    { 
        f(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 Despite the `Tag` property involving a lot of casting from `Object` and really not being my favorite solution...